# How do I increase a score and print it in the console?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm still trying to finish off my very simple game but I've ran into another problem.
I want the Console to print ("*Player's score*") everytime the ball touches the sidewalls. So i created a new script and called it ScoreManager that should take care of this function. But the only thing the console does is print (0). this is the code.

```
void Update()
{
    //boundaries 
    if (Ball.transform.position.x < -5.61f)
    {
        RightScore++;
        print(RightScore);
    }

    if (Ball.transform.position.x > 5.5f)
    {
        LeftScore++;
        print(LeftScore);
    }
            
}
```

Comment: There's not much we do to help you with so few debugging details. It's printing 0 because the value is 0.

Comment: Is 'print' a routine you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

`RightScore` and `LeftScore` are not defined. If you define them, it should work:

```
private int RightScore = 0;
private int LeftScore = 0;

void Update()
{
    //boundaries 
    if (Ball.transform.position.x < -5.61f)
    {
        RightScore++;
        print(RightScore);
    }

    if (Ball.transform.position.x > 5.5f)
    {
        LeftScore++;
        print(LeftScore);
    }
            
}
```